# Can the FileHelpers library write classes containing nullable fields as well as read them?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm using version 2.0 of the FileHelpers library which is documented as being able to handle .NET 2.0 Nullable types.

I'm using the code given in the example from the documentation:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]   
public class Orders   
{   
    public int OrderID;   

    public DateTime? OrderDate;   

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]     
    public DateTime? RequiredDate;   

    public int? ShipVia;   
}
```

With a FileHelperEngine I can successfully read in a file which has no value for the OrderDate, RequiredDate or ShipVia fields. The file looks like:

1|||

However, I cannot then write out the resulting Orders[] to file - the library throws a NullReferenceException, stack trace below:

at FileHelpers.ConvertHelpers.CultureConverter.FieldToString(Object from)
   at FileHelpers.FieldBase.BaseFieldString(Object fieldValue)
   at FileHelpers.DelimitedField.CreateFieldString(StringBuilder sb, Object fieldValue)
   at FileHelpers.FieldBase.AssignToString(StringBuilder sb, Object fieldValue)
   at FileHelpers.RecordInfo.RecordToString(Object record)
   at FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine`1.WriteStream(TextWriter writer, IEnumerable`1 records, Int32 maxRecords)
   at FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine`1.WriteFile(String fileName, IEnumerable`1 records, Int32 maxRecords)
   at FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine`1.WriteFile(String fileName, IEnumerable`1 records)
   at TestingFileHelpers.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev\src\TestingFileHelpers\TestingFileHelpers\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I'm sure I must be missing something here but I cannot figure out what it is. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with the last version of the library:

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=21768&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt65  (login as guest)

If that version dot fix the error just tell me in a comment and I will add a test case to the lib to ensure it works

Comment: Yes, seems to be fixed in that version. Thanks!

Comment: I was having the exact same problem, but on a nullable decimal. I pulled down the latest build from the above link and it also fixed me up. Can I recommened @nowhere_fast that you update the web page to reference this new build? It would have saved me a bunch of time! Luckily, StackOverflow came through (like always) with an answer.

Comment: @MarcosMeli can you update your sourcefourge site to reference the builds available on TeamCity?  I looked there initially and could not find a link -- luckily, I found my old post here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[FieldNullValue("")]` attribute to specify default values for the empty fields.

Comment: This attribute can't be added to a field of type int? - it results in a BadUsageException being raised when instantiating the FileHelperEngine, as the value provided ("") is not a nullable int. I don't think this attribute is the answer as it is used to assign a "magic value" of the given type when no value is provided in the file i.e. this is pre-nullable types.