# Null Value Found. You must specify a NullValueAttribute

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm using the FileHelpers Library to import and process a spreadsheet. I'm having a problem with a couple of properties of the entity. I added the `[FieldNullValue(null)]` attribute to both properties but it had no effect. I still get the same error. Did I miss something?

```
[FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
[FieldConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
[FieldNullValue(null)]
private DateTime? _EstDueDate;
[FieldOptional()]
[FieldNullValue(null)]
private int? _ID;
```

UPDATE:
I went ahead and set the default values in the Attribute `[FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), "2000-1-1]` then when I send it to the service call to write to the database I checked the field and set it to null if it's the default date not the optimal solution but it's not much overhead. I can deal with a default value for the ID being 0 that indicates to the service that it's a new record anyway

Comment: [FieldNullValue()] is used to define what the property is if null, I don't think it works with nullable types. Have you checked this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066255/can-the-filehelpers-library-write-classes-containing-nullable-fields-as-well-as

Comment: I did check that earlier. It didn't resolve it. I have used this library with csv files and delimited files and have had no problem with it identifying the nullable types in the entity and acting accordingly. I'm guessing this is specific to the ExcelStorage.ExtractRecords() method.